# How to handle subclasses in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans

I've two classes (A and B) that extend a base class BASE. I need to make a report that takes an array of such classes and the prints the fields of A or B. I tought of using conditional expressions, then casting to one or another (depending on a field value). But I can't cast, because I don't know how to refere to the current bean.

To do this I am using a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` filled with a `List<BASE>`. How do I cast every bean to A or B in a report (or subreport)? I tried:

```
((A)this)
```

but it says basically that this contains the report instance, not the current bean and gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `((A) BASE)` suppose `BASE` is your BASE class

now `BASE` point to `the current record`